# How can I compute the value of the following Legendre symbols?

Tags: number-theory

I have read more examples how can I compute the value of Legendre symbols, but I can't find the right way with these examples. The prime factorisation have to help, but I can't apply it in these examples:
$$\left(\frac{7}{31}\right) = ?,\qquad
  \left(\frac{59}{107}\right) = ?,\qquad
  \left(\frac{141}{181}\right) = ?
$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the law of quadratic reciprocity? Have you tried to apply it in these cases (after factoring any non-primes)?

Comment: yes I tried to apply the quadratic reciprocity but I have no idea how can I compute the values, can you maybe help me? Thank yo very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, since $31$ and $7$ are both $\equiv 3\pod{4}$, we have
\begin{equation*}
  \left(\frac{7}{31}\right) = -\left(\frac{31}{7}\right) = -\left(\frac{3}{7}\right) = -(-1) = 1.
\end{equation*}
The others are similar, but you need to watch out for non-primes.

Comment: can you maybe help me to solve also the other problems? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You should be able to do the others from what I've given you. If not, it sounds like to you need to go back and read and understand the material again. Sorry.

Comment: okay, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the properties of the Legendre symbol as pointed out. In addition, to verify your trials, you really should try to use a computer algebra system, like Sage or Pari. The command is "kronecker(a,b)". The result is:
$$
kronecker(7,31)=1, \quad kronecker(59,107)=-1, \quad kronecker(141,181)=-1.
$$
For a tutorial, try this [link](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/GPTutorial.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Can you maybe show you the long way of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

For $\left(\frac{59}{107}\right)$ both are $ 3 \bmod 4$ so we have $-\left(\frac{107}{59}\right)$. Now since $107 \equiv 48 \bmod 59$ we have $\left(\frac{48}{59}\right)$. Then we need to factor 48 and it is $2*2*2*2*3$ but notice that the two's all cancel so we have $-\left(\frac{3}{59}\right)$. Now I think you should be able to do the rest of this problem yourself. There are about 3 more steps. Good luck!